# how to send data via header function like post

Tags: php, post, header

I try to pass data from php file to another php file with header function.  like that:

```
header("location:login.php?userName=$username");
```

(that line appear in the first php file.)  the problem is that the data appear in the url of the second php file. like GET. I try looking for some example but without success. i looking for  how to make it like POST?

Comment: So basically what you're tring to do is transfer variables/values from one file to another? Is there any particular reason you want to do it this way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Pass POST variables with header()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447211/php-pass-post-variables-with-header)

Answer (score 7):

You can't. If you redirect you'll always have a GET request.

A possible solution (if the target script is on the same domain) would be using PHP sessions to store the data on the server.

Comment: I try to make login to web site. there are 3 files. html with from that pass data via post to php file. that php file need to check the log in according to the database. if the log in success we pass to another php file that show result that match to this user. I do not want the values ​​appear in the URL.For safety reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Originally suggesting to use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php), I now believe that it might not be the best solution.  If you're simply looking to preserve or pass data between scripts, you might want to look into Sessions, which allow you to set and preserve data between scripts.

eg:

**Script 1**

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['userName'] = $username;
```

**Script 2**

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['userName']))
    $username = $_SESSION['userName'];

echo $username;
```

This will successfully pass the value of $username between two scripts.  Simply put any variables into the $_SESSION array and they will be available throughout your scripts.

- Be sure to include session_start(); at the top of every script
- Look at also including [session_set_cookie_params()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to be sure your sessions are available through your domain and/or don't conflict with other site's sessions.

Comment: This makes the server send a request, not the client. So it's probably not what he wants.

Comment: How do you make the browser do a post to the new destination using cURL?

Comment: Re-reading the question, curl might not be the best solution for this.

Comment: I try to make login to web site. there are 3 files.

Comment: Ortal, this would work for checking if users are logged in.  After you've authenticated the user, simply set their username in the $_SESSION array and check if that variable is present on every other page that is "inside" the logged in section of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PEAR's excellent [HTTP_Request2](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) package to [make POST requests](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.http.http-request2.request.php#package.http.http-request2.request.body).