# Why $_POST array is null?

Tags: php, post

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'tests');
    $_POST['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/45';
    $_POST['old_value']='1';
    $_POST['value']='2';
    header("Location: http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record");
?>
```

I need to set $_POST array in this script and load script by url. But the script from url tells me that $_POST array is null. Why? How can I set the $_POST array and send it to script by url? Thank you in advance.

UPDATE:
I have some code which must be tested, and there is some script on the url `"http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record"`, and it uses values from $_POST array; so, I can't change this script, and I want to test it. How can I do it?

UPDATE2:

```
<?php
    //include ('\application\controllers\welcome.php');
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'tests');
    $_POST_DATA=array();
    $_POST_DATA['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/45';
    $_POST_DATA['old_value']='1';
    $_POST_DATA['value']='2';
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST_DATA);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Did you mean to override the parameters, and instead `include()` the update script from the current webserver? Then don't use the URL, use the filesystem path to do so.

Comment: Please, are there any ways to send $_POST array into another script without forms? May be JS, or other mean?

Comment: Yes, there are. Please refrain from comment spamming though.

Comment: OK, sorry, but I'm confused. Could you describe this mean please?

Comment: No, you have to enhance your question first. Explain why you need that specific data transfer, can't use the answers given so far, and how the two application parts are to be connected. Else your question is too broad. -- Use the edit link. -- To get higher quality answers, write a [higher quality question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) by including [sample code](http://sscce.org/) that is complete yet concise, etc.

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please, look at it.

Comment: If it's for testing purposes, then use the cURL API or commandline curl tool to isse a direct request containing POST params.

Comment: `<form action='http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record' method='post' name='auto'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='AccountPagesView.a_book/45'></input>
<input type='hidden' name='old_value' value='1'></input>
<input type='hidden' name='value' value='2'></input>
<script>
document.auto.submit();
</script>
</form>`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. A redirect will always result in the target page loaded via GET.

However, you could use the session to store these values. Call `session_start();` on both pages and use the superglobal array `$_SESSION` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Please, are there any ways to send $_POST array into another script without forms? May be JS, or other mean?

Comment: If you want it to be redirect-ish you need to create a form (possibly with only hidden fields) and then submit it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you need to send POST values from one PHP script to another, without using JS, If you absolutely don't want to use `$_SESSION` though that is what you should be using.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array('id' => 'AccountPagesView.a_book/45', 'old_value' => '1', 'value' => '2',);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://path-to/other.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` only exists if the request was sent through the `POST` method, which means a form was sent.

You could use `$_SESSION` instead.

Comment: Please, are there any ways to send $_POST array into another script without forms? May be JS, or other mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the prime reason why $_SESSION's should be used. See this other question for an explanation: [PHP - Pass POST variables with header()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447211/php-pass-post-variables-with-header)

```
<?php
session_start();
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'tests');
$_SESSION['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/45';
$_SESSION['old_value']='1';
$_SESSION['value']='2';
header("Location: http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record");
```

Then on index.php/welcome/update_record

```
<?php
session_start();
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'tests');
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$old_value =  $_SESSION['old_value'];
$value = $_SESSION['value'];

//do something
```

Comment: Please, are there any ways to send $_POST array into another script without forms? May be JS, or other mean?

Answer (score 0):

Two answers.
If the following does not work:

```
<?php
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'tests');
    $_POST['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/45';
    $_POST['old_value']='1';
    $_POST['value']='2';
    require("/index.php/welcome/update_record");
?>
```

*(I am a bit flabbergasted about the page URL.)*

Then:

As you insist on POST (as is your right in asking), you can do:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/index.php/welcome/update_record" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="AccountPagesView.a_book/45">
      <input type="hidden" name="old_value" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="value" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="ENVIRONMENT" value="tests">
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       document.forms[0].submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where that define of ENVIRONMENT needs to be solved somehow.

If the target script uses $_REQUEST which is $_POST + $_GET (i.o. $_POST) then you do a HTTP GET URL: `...-?id=...&old_value=1&value=2` which would be the simplest solution.